# Can't Delete Version in Google Tag Mangaer ("GTM")

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've created, but not published, a version in GTM. My version has the status "Latest". I want to delete this version. When I try I get an error box popping up to say

> Container Version In Use 
>   The Version 3 is in use and cannot be
>   deleted.

What do I need to do to be able to delete this version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to reassign a different version of your container to be latest first. The latest workspace is the one shown in your GTM backend (all the tags, triggers and variables you see). If you were to delete the latest version, GTM wouldn't know which tags, triggers and variables to display. You always have a latest and a live version. If you want to delete the particular version that is latest you will have to switch to a previous version first:

1. Navigate to Versions
2. Choose the version you want to be shown in the GTM backend
3. Click on the corresponding "Action" button and choose "Set as latest Version"
4. Click on the "Action" button and choose "Delete" for the version you want deleted

Also, note that you can have multiple workspaces within the latest version that have to merged before publishing. If you change something in one workspace you will have to update the others in order to see the changes:
[image: Update prompt for new container version in GTM]

This applies to changes between versions as well. If you set a new version as latest, you will have to update your workspace in order to get the tags, triggers and variables displayed.